# perform join on Azure StorageClient

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

whats the easiest way to replicate the join behavior when I am using Storageclient for windows Azure

Comment: Could you provide some further details please?

Comment: Nicholas, it was the wrong idea on the wrong platform, its better to rethink the solution instead of using joins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long story short. You can't replicate the join behavior when you work with the Table Storage; or, more precisely, **any solution, that achieves such behavior, comes with terrible performance**. Thus, what the point of using Table Storage, if your code does not scale at all?

With Table Storage, you have to think your design from the start not to need any *Join*.

Comment: I agree with you on that Joannes, I was looking at small part that needed a simple join to get it to work, but then it hit me that I better get things away from such approach if I wanted my app to scale beyond the simple , drop the app on azure approach.

thanks for taking the time to reply